# running java [-options] -jar jarfile (no explicit classname given)

Tags: java, jar

Please correct me if I am wrong.

When running `java [-options] -jar jarfile` with no explicit class name, if a single class exists within the jar that contains a `public static void main(String[] args)` method, that method will be invoked automatically. Right?

What happens if I have several classes that contain an eligible `main` method?

Comment: Thanks all! I guess I should have know that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It uses the Main-Class defined in the MANIFEST file to determine which class contains the main method that should be run.

see http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Comment: Note: If you're using Ant to do your building, it's possible to have Ant build your MANIFEST file for you. I've found it to be very handy to not have to manually keep that file up to date.

Answer (score 4):

The class to run is taken from the [Manifest metadata](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/jar/jar.html).

> Main-Class :
>
> The value of this attribute defines
>   the relative path of the main
>   application class which the launcher
>   will load at startup time. The value
>   must not have the .class extension
>   appended to the class name.

Comment: Great answer, sorry I can't choose more than one as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

The JAR must contain a [manifest file](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#JAR%20Manifest) with a "Main-Class" entry.

Edit: I recall at one point the docs were incorrect. If "Main-Class" doesn't work for you, try "Main-class" (lowercase "class").

Answer (score 2):

Which class' main is run is determined by the [MANIFEST](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/jar/jar.html#Main%20Attributes) file inside the .jar. Specifically the `Main-Class` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

If you attempt to use java -jar on a jar without the above said manifest, you'll get the following output:

```
Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from <jarname>.jar
```